Arduino IDE compilation segmentation fault
Several years ago, I created a sketch for an ESP8266 (NodeMCU 12E) to log-on to my local network and then switch a relay on or off in response to an ON or OFF string message on a subscribed MQTT TOPIC. All worked fine until recently, when the relay just stuck on ON, even if I manually published an ON or OFF using mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.7.245 -p 1883 -t "bathroom/fanSwitch" -m "OFF in a terminal.
I have dug out what I believe is the original code, but it won't compile and I can't tell from the Output what the problem is: Here's the code and the compiler output from just before the segmentation fault (not the whole lot, though I can supply more if needed)
Code
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPPubSubClientWrapper.h>

// Network & MQTT constants
const char* ssid = "MySSID";
const char* password = "********";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.7.245";
const char* topic = "bathroom/fanSwitch";
//const uint16_t *mqtt_port = {1883};

const int FanRelay = 13; //D7
String strTopic;
String strPayload;

ESPPubSubClientWrapper client(mqtt_server); //, mqtt_port);

/*
This function will be called if topic "bathroom/fanSwitch" is received on MQTT and echo the payload on Serial monitor.
It uses the simplified API with payload being converted to a 0 terminated char pointer (or NULL if no payload was sent)
*/  
void callbackHeater(char* topic, char * payload) {
  Serial.println("\r\nMessage ""Fan instruction"" received");
  if (strPayload == "ON")
  {
    Serial.printf("Payload-len=%d, Payload=\"%s\"\r\n", strlen(payload), payload);
    digitalWrite(FanRelay, HIGH);
  }
  else if (strPayload == "OFF")
    Serial.println("Payload is NULL.");
    digitalWrite(FanRelay, LOW);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  client.on("ON", callbackHeater);
  client.on("OFF", callbackHeater);


  pinMode(FanRelay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(FanRelay, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  client.loop();
}

Compiler output
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -DESP8266 @/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/build.opt -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core -c @/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/warnings/default-cppflags -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -Werror=return-type -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" "-DARDUINO_BOARD_ID=\"nodemcuv2\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266 -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/variants/nodemcu /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_si2c.cpp -o /tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/core_esp8266_si2c.cpp.o
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -DESP8266 @/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/build.opt -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core -c @/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/warnings/default-cppflags -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -Werror=return-type -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" "-DARDUINO_BOARD_ID=\"nodemcuv2\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266 -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/variants/nodemcu /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_sigma_delta.cpp -o /tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/core_esp8266_sigma_delta.cpp.o
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -DESP8266 @/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/build.opt -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core -c @/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/warnings/default-cppflags -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -Werror=return-type -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" "-DARDUINO_BOARD_ID=\"nodemcuv2\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266 -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/variants/nodemcu /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_spi_utils.cpp -o /tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/core_esp8266_spi_utils.cpp.o
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -DESP8266 @/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/build.opt -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core -c @/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/warnings/default-cppflags -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -Werror=return-type -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" "-DARDUINO_BOARD_ID=\"nodemcuv2\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266 -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/variants/nodemcu /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_timer.cpp -o /tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/core_esp8266_timer.cpp.o
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -DESP8266 @/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/build.opt -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core -c @/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/warnings/default-cppflags -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -Werror=return-type -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" "-DARDUINO_BOARD_ID=\"nodemcuv2\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266 -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/variants/nodemcu /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_vm.cpp -o /tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/core_esp8266_vm.cpp.o
In file included from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/unordered_map:46,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/functional:61,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/coredecls.h:36,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/PolledTimeout.h:30,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.cpp:30:
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/bits/hashtable.h:878:7: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
  878 |       {
      |       ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -DESP8266 @/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/build.opt -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core -c @/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/tools/warnings/default-cppflags -Os -g -free -fipa-pta -Werror=return-type -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++17 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DMMU_IRAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMMU_ICACHE_SIZE=0x8000 -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU_ESP12E\"" "-DARDUINO_BOARD_ID=\"nodemcuv2\"" -DLED_BUILTIN=2 -DFLASHMODE_DIO -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266 -I/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/variants/nodemcu /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_waveform_phase.cpp -o /tmp/arduino/sketches/C68E38205E22027FC6E051ECD33B38AA/core/core_esp8266_waveform_phase.cpp.o
In file included from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/vector:67,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/functional:62,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/algorithm:74,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/Arduino.h:229,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/wiring_private.h:31,
                 from /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_timer.cpp:21:
/home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/10.3.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1853:2: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
 1853 |  { return empty() ? nullptr : std::__to_address(__ptr); }
      |  ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.

Using library ESP8266WiFi at version 1.0 in folder: /home/greg/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.1.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi 
Using library ESPPubSubClientWrapper at version 1.0.2 in folder: /home/greg/Arduino/libraries/ESPPubSubClientWrapper 
Using library PubSubClient at version 2.8 in folder: /home/greg/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient 
exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1

I invoke the IDE (2.3.2) as follows ~/Downloads/arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit/arduino-ide --disable-gpucd on OpenSuSE Tumbleweed + KDE/Plasma6/Wayland
uname -a
Linux tranquility 6.10.9-1-default #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Sep  8 13:43:05 UTC 2024 (5af7788) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Both
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPPubSubClientWrapper.h>

are installed and up-to-date.
Can anyone see a glaring error or know a next step to find the error

Could there be a disparity between the module/library versions which were installed in an earlier version and those needed by the IDE 2.3.2 version I'm running here?
